# How to choose two near each other values randomly

Tags: java, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I have a function to print all coordinates into a list (col and row) wherein the grid I have 0. However, I want to procedure it and use it to randomly choose a place to generate there 1. How do I do it? As for me, the output of the list does look quite messy.

Code:

```
  public static void addNewNum(int[][]grid) {
        List freeSpace = new ArrayList();
        for(int row=0; row< grid.length; row++)  {
            for(int col=0; col< grid[row].length; col++) {
                if (grid[row][col] ==0) {
                    freeSpace.add(col);
                    freeSpace.add(row);
                }
        
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(freeSpace.toArray()));
         }
     }
```

As output I have :

```
  1   2   3   4   
  ================
 1| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 
   --+---+---+--
 2| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 
   --+---+---+--
 3| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 
   --+---+---+--
 4| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 
  ================
[0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

*List is printed in format col1,row1,col2,row2,col3,row3... And i need to choose somehow randomly near each other values so they would be like a valid coordinate ( I cannot choose col1,col2 or row2,col3 ) Maybe it is done easier, and I should create other list, but that is the list that I came up with ( Also output of list looks kind of strange )*

SO basically it should work like

1. Generated List with coordinates
2. Choose right coordinates ( example: col2,row2 )
3. Change it with value 1 in array

Comment: As the answer to your other question says, use a class to hold a pair of coordinates. Then pick a random index into the `List` and use those coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to build and use a *typed* list of pairs of the coordinates:

```java
public static List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> getEmptyCells(int[][] grid) {
    List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            if (0 == grid[i][j]) {
                result.add(new Pair(i, j));
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
// ....

List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> emptyCells = getEmptyCells(grid);

Random r = new Random();
Pair<Integer, Integer> freeCell = emptyCells.get(r.nextInt(emptyCells.size()));

grid[freeCell.getFirst()][freeCell.getSecond()];
```

If the list of pairs is not the option and the coordinates are represented as in shown the question in `List<Integer>`, then the size of the list is always even, so the index of the pair is calculated for a half of the list and it is in range [0, list.size()/2), and the coordinates of grid cells can be calculated as: `row = 2 * i; col = 2 * i + 1;` as shown below:

```java
public static List<Integer> getEmptyCellPairs(int[][] grid) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            if (0 == grid[i][j]) {
                result.add(i);
                result.add(j);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}


List<Integer> emptyCellPairs = getEmptyCellPairs(grid);

Random r = new Random();

int pairIndex = r.nextInt(emptyCellPairs.size() / 2);

// free cell
grid[emptyCells.get(2 * pairIndex)][emptyCells.get(2 * pairIndex + 1)];
```

Comment: the problem with this comes that  pairIndex is usually is out of range, and I wanted to ask whether  how should I last the last line of code * your second solution

Comment: Right, the appropriate indexes _in grid_ should be retrieved from `emptyCells` list, sorry.  @Zexxxx, you may check the update